# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I just re-downloaded some code that I had on github a while back, and for some reason it no longer works. It gives the error that is in the title.
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtWnD.png). I didn't change any code, but now it doesnt work. Could you please let me know what is incorrect? BTW this is in Firebase realtime database, not firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change 1 line of code
Where you write

```
let events = data.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
```

Change it to

```
let events = data.value as! [String:Any]
```

Comment: this gives an error in the line that says "let event  = Event...". The error says Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts and has no fix options. how do i fix this?